# comparing a number with an array item in smarty

Tags: smarty

This is what I would like to do:

I have assigned the following items:

```
$smarty->assign('seats', $aantalStoeltjes);
$smarty->assign('taken', $bezetArray);
```

"seats" is the number of seats available. This is an array with only one item. The number 150 in this case but is dynamic.
"taken" is the seats that are already taken and should not be displayed. This is also an array with several items in it like movietitle, play day, etc.  The taken seats are assigned to "seatnumber".

What I need is to let smarty to add `foo` 150 times (in this case). If the seat's number is equal to the taken number the `foo` should not be added.

So to sum it up.
`foo` should be added 150 times in this case, but if the number is equal to one of the seatnumbers in the "taken" array it should be skipped.

This is what I tried:

```
{section start=1 loop=$seats+1 step=1}
    {foreach from=$taken item=tolate}
        {if $smarty.section.seats.index !=  $tolate.seatnumber}
        <p>{$tolate.seatnumber}</p>
        <p>{$smarty.section.seats.index}</p>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/section}
```

but this doesn't work correctly.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand a thing what you need. Which `foo` are you talking about? Your code seems trying to do something completely different from what you described. Also if `$seats` is an array then what does `loop=$seats+1` mean? Does `$seats` always contain only one number? Then why not just get that number from an array and work with it instead of adding extra loop for an array with 1 number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much simple if you would use this:

```
{foreach from=$taken item=tolate} 
    {if $tolate.seatnumber != $seats} 
          <p>{$tolate.seatnumber}</p> 
          <p>{$seats}</p> 
    {/if} 
{/foreach}
```